# Sort in "original order" when using DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sorting, distinct

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](20) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [TableB] ([id],[FileName])VALUES(1,'File2')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
INSERT INTO [TableB] ([id],[FileName])VALUES(2,'File1')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
INSERT INTO [TableB] ([id],[FileName])VALUES(3,'File1')
```

When I do a simple `SELECT`, it gives following results:

```
id          FileName            
----------- --------------------
          1 File2               
          2 File1               
          3 File1
```

But, when I add the `DISTINCT` it gives:

```
FileName            
--------------------
File1               
File2
```

I dont need the sorting, I need results something like below:

```
FileName            
--------------------
File2               
File1
```

I am working on SQL Server 2008.  I want to maintain the original order of the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want the results to be ordered by the first id recorded for each FileName, try:

```
select FileName
from TableB
group by FileName
order by min(id)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between `order by id` and `order by min(id)` in this context?

Comment: `min(id)` is the smallest value of `id` within the group. `order by id` is not a valid sort order in a grouped query that isn't grouped by `id`, because there could be multiple values of `id` for each row returned; there would be no way to determine which value should be used for sorting purposes.

Answer (score 4):

The fact is that you don't know the order of tuples in database. You can relogin and they will be ordered in another way. That is why there is no such thing as `original order`.

Answer (score 3):

As Andrew answered, row ordering is done internally and we dont have control over it. Hence for your problem i suggest adding a column like "timestamp" which keeps the timestamp of row insert.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the database engine needs to use an algorithm in order to eliminate the duplicates when you use `DISTINCT`. It can be by inserting the elements into the equivalent of a `std::set` (C++). It can only be done via a hash function.

Remember that a table in a relational database is a collection of rows with no natural order. If you want a natural order in your rows you have to give them a sequence number or an id, and always use `ORDER BY` in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

if you 'need' the results in a specific order, then you should declare that order in an ORDER BY clause.

like

```
SELECT FileName
FROM mytable
ORDER BY FileName Desc
```